# Formatting Highcharts Series

Tags: jquery, formatting, highcharts

I have a chart looking like the following.

[image: Chart]

I have two seperate qusetions:

1. How can i have a "." accour as the thousands seperator on the series (there is one in the tooltip when you hover over the data). I have tried looking into plotoptions and numberformat, but have not been able to work this out.
2. How to approach the issue of data becoming so small, that the numbers are hard to make out.

I realise question number 2 is much more open-ended, but any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Graph:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    Highcharts.setOptions({
                        lang: {
                            thousandsSep: '.'
                        }
                    });

                        var tapegraph = {
                            colors: [
                                     '#525051'
                            ],
                            exporting: { enabled: false },
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'tapecontainer',
                            type: 'column'
                        },
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Tapeforbrug'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: []
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Gigabyte'
                            },
                            stackLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                style: {
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            align: 'right',
                            x: -100,
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            y: 5,
                            floating: true,
                            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                            borderColor: '#CCC',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            shadow: false
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                stacking: 'normal',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series: []
                    };

                        $.get("../classic_3270/KMDprod1/INFO.CPU.REPORT.MFTAPE" + kunde + ".txt", function (data) {
                            var lines = data.split('\n');
                            lines = data.trim().split('\n');
                        $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
                            var items = line.split(',');

                            if (lineNo == 0) {
                                $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                                    if (itemNo > 0) tapegraph.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                                })
                                ;
                            }

                            else {
                                var series = {
                                    pointWidth: 42,
                                    data: []

                                };
                                $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                                    if (itemNo == 0) {
                                        series.name = item;
                                    } else {
                                        series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                                    }
                                });

                                tapegraph.series.push(series);
                            }

                        });

                        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(tapegraph);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Set thousandSep to '.' and will work, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/310/

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        thousandsSep: '.'
    }
});
```

2) Well, you can just hide that labels - for such thing use dataLabels.formatter and check if value is below something like 5% of total, and decide to display or not that dataLabel.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer. In fact thsi is the exact thing i had tried already. But with no result. I have included the source for my Graph in my original post. Do you have any idea what could cause this? The examples i have found, suggest that this should be correct.

Comment: Put your code into jsFiddle, which will show that error. I know you have AJAX - put response from AJAX as single string (it's CSV, right?)  so it would work even in jsfiddle.

Comment: Fiddling around with this made me find the answer myself, it seems i was using an old version of Highcharts.